# Django rest framework Authentication not recognizing User

Tags: django-rest-framework

when i use "IsAdminUser" or "IsAuthenticated" i can no longer accesee the api View and it says "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

it works normally when i set it as "AllowAny" or when i don't set Authentication at all.

Views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics, status, permissions
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

class CreatePost(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_auth',
    'corsheaders',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig'
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination'
}
```

Comment: You are not providing Authentication information in your request. Include the request you're doing

Comment: i don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide authentication details in your header because you have activated TokenAuthentication in your DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES, as the response tells you.
This means that you should add an Authorization header to your request with a token, which you have to create for each user.
E.g using curl to send a request:

```
curl --request POST '127.0.0.1:8000/yourendpoint/'
--header 'Authorization: c2vU15dD.kurnNras5GFM7oP0jsv4Bdasdsadas'
```

Read more here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

The default token authentication scheme in DRF is quite barebones, you should consider a package like Djoser. If not, read the instructions in the link and you'll be good to go.

If this helps you, please mark it as an answer on the left.